# How can I write the current url into an href attribute?

Tags: jquery

I found out how to write the current url into an element:

```
  <p id="example"></p>

    <script>
    document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = 
    window.location.href;
    </script>
```

My result is:

```
http://www.animalfriends.de/shop/
```

Now the difficult part is, that I have this link:

```
<a href="#top">Go to top</a>
```

and I want to get the current page url into the `href` before the `#top` and delete the last `/` so the result would look in the end like this:

```
<a id="gototop" href="http://www.animalfriends.de/shop#top">Go to top</a>
```

I tried something like this, but I am lost:

```
$(#gototop).attr('href', 'window.location.href;');
```

Maybe it is not possible?

Comment: Why? If `id="top"` is at top of page browser will do this automatically without changing the href. Looks like a hack for some other problem

Comment: FYI: That first bit of code that uses `innerHTML` is an XSS attack vector, in case you were planning on using it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With jQuery:

```
$("#gototop").attr("href", window.location.href);
```

With JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("gototop").href = window.location.href;
```

If you'd like to add `#top` to the URL, just change `window.location.href` to `window.location.href + "#top"`.

**Why didn't your code work?**
So there's two reasons why the code below didn't work for you.

```
$(#gototop).attr('href', 'window.location.href;');
```

1. The argument accepted by `$()` should be a string (or a variable containing a string). You didn't declare the `#gototop` variable. (on a sidenote, it's not possible to declare a variable with a name starting with `#`) You also didn't say it was a string (you'd need to surround it with single or double quotes, like `"#gototop"` or `'#gototop'`.
2. `window.location.href` is a property (containing a string) within the `window` global variable. So you should pass it without single or double quotes, because else you're passing it as a string instead of a variable.